# Django: passing multiple values into the dictionary of the render method

Tags: python, django

I try to send multiple values to the render dictionary method, but I can just reach the first value in my template.

my views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import generic

from books.models import Book
from places.models import Symbol

class IntroView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'books/intro.html'

def intro(request, book_id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
    symbol_list = Symbol.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'books/intro.html', {'book': book, 'symbol_list': symbol_list})
```

and my intro.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h2>{{ book.name }}</h2>
<h3>{{ book.catch_line }}</h3>
<em>{{ book.publication_year }}</em>

<hr />

<h4>Symbols</h4>
{% if symbol_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for symbol in symbol_list %}
        <li><img src="{{ symbol.icon.url }}"/>{{ symbol.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No symbols yet...</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

In the template `symbol_list` is always empty but the model have some values.

**[EDIT]** my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from books import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.IntroView.as_view(), name='intro'),
)
```

Comment: You're passing it in fine - so I don't think it's to do with multiple values being passed in to `render` (you can check that for yourself by passing `book` in "after" `symbol_list`). Try putting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` just before your call to `render`, and have a look at what's in `symbol_list` (see http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/ if you've not used `pdb` before).

Comment: Would you mind `print symbol_list` just before the `return render(...)` and seeing it in the console? Btw, you have a class based view and function view. Which one are you using in the urlConf?

Comment: I just added my urls.py file. I guess that I use the class and not the function... Sorry, but this is my first experience with django and python.

Comment: Can you please check if that is working: urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^(?P<book_id>\d+)/$', 'intro'),
) Thanks

Comment: @Marc_O - yep, you're using the class-based view not the function view . Hopefully the answer I just added will get you there :). Welcome to Django/Python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the class-based view `IntroView`, which you don't pass in `symbol_list` with, as you identified.

Try modifying your view as follows:

```
class IntroView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'books/intro.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IntroView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['symbol_list'] = Symbol.objects.all().order_by('name')
        return context
```